# Multiple products in single charge Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

My use case is that I have multiple products some of which are one time payment and others are recurring payment products. I want to charge the user only once so that the user doesn't have to pay for each product separately. According to my study we can create multiple product subscriptions with one charge. https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiple-products#creating

If I had one-time payment products only, I can only receive one payment of the payment amount for selected products (as sum of prices).

But as I have mentioned I have some products which are recurring payment. So my question is if I add one-time payment products in this subscription request will they be charged again ones the recurring period overs, and if yes how can I Implement the above case in PHP?

**Note:** I want to implement this in custom form. I don't want to be redirected to stripe page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) and combine both [one-time and recurring prices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-line_items:%7E:text=Use%20this%20parameter%20to%20pass%20one%2Dtime%20or%20recurring)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRttu.png).
You can follow this [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart?client=html&lang=php) in order to integrate Stripe Checkout with PHP.

Here what it will looks like for combining both prices types, the first charge will be for both pricing, and the second charge will be just for the recurring price(s):
[image: Stripe Checkout Example - one-time and recurring prices]

Comment: Checkout has three modes: `payment`, `subscription`, or `setup`. Use `payment` mode for one-time purchases. What should I use in modes if I have the following cases
-> **One-time and recurring both products are selected**
-> **Only one-time products are selected**
-> **Only recurring products are selected**

Comment: - One-time and recurring both products are selected: subscription
- Only one-time products are selected: payment
- Only recurring products are selected: subscription

Stripe Checkout setup mode is for saving a PaymentMethod. More details can be found here:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=checkout